# Create log file using crontab as different user not working

Tags: bash, cron, cron-task

I am trying to use crontab running as a different user(due to required permissions) to create log files but my script doesnt seem to be executing

I am currently logged in as `admin` and I want to run the script as `www-data` so to edit the crontab I am using

```
sudo crontab -u www-data -e
```

Then entering

```
* * * * * /path/to/sh/mkLogFile.sh
```

mkLogFile.sh is a file that is owned by www-data

`-rwxrw-r--  1 www-data www-data    58 May 22 10:08 mkLogFile.sh`

and its contents are

```
tday=`date +"%y%m%d%h%m"

`touch /path/to/log/$tday.log`
```

In the crontab I have also tried the following without making the file first

```
* * * * * /path/to/file/populateLogs >/path/to/log`date +%y%d%m`.log
```

none of these work to either create the file or to create and populate the file.

If I run any of these using

`sudo -u www-data ./mkLogFile.sh`

or any other command from the crontab they work, but not when run from the crontab. Other scripts have run in this way just none that make a file.

the `log` dir is also owned by `www-data` and has full permissions.

`drwxrwxrwx   2 www-data www-data   4096 May 22 10:40 log`

Is there something glaringly obvious that I'm doing wrong ? or is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: This may be just a typo, but you're missing a backtick on the first line of mkLogFile.sh, and you have two unnecessary backticks on the second line.  Someone will probably be along to tell you that it's considered preferable to use the `$()` syntax instead, i.e.  `tday=$(date +"%y%m%d%h%m")`

Comment: Thank you, it is now making files. and idea why `>/path/to/log\`date +%y%d%m\`.log` wasn't working ?

Comment: It is a matter of escaping the date strings. Check the duplicate.

Comment: @fedorqui escaping the date string has not solved the issue

Comment: @Cob50nm please share your last attempt, so we can see.